# what is the best way to use gnumake with hudson

Tags: hudson

what is the best way to use gnumake with hudson?

Comment: I think more details are in order.

Answer (score 2):

I just set up jobs as normal and have the build step be a shell command "cd ${WORKSPACE}; make all"